# tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization does not accept float64 as input type

Tags: tensorflow, keras

here is an example to reproduce the error below!

```
import tensorflow.keras.layers as tks
input_ = tks.Input(shape=[None, None, 3], dtype='float64')
conv = tks.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=3)(input_)
batch = tks.BatchNormalization()(conv)
```

I am running `tensorflow 1.14 and keras 2.4.0`

**TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'x' has DataType float64 not in list of allowed values: float32**

Comment: What's your question? The error message is quite clear. Use `float32`.

Comment: @xdurch0, Why it does not accept `float64`

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a TF developer.